# sql server date stored in table comparing with the system date

Tags: sql-server, date-conversion

really struggling to convert the below date format 10.11.2013 in the format
of the system date.

I have a request to compare column data with the system date.
In the column the date is storing as DD.MM.YYYY

Or we need to convert system date (getdate()) to the date values stored in the database table.

Thanks in Advance

Regards,
Dev

Comment: Could you please show some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve? The question, in its current wording, is a bit hard to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

> convert system date (getdate()) to the date values stored in the
>   database table.

Gives formats as `DD.MM.YYYY`

```
select CONVERT( CHAR(10),GETDATE(),104) -- outputs 11.09.2014
```

with Your Column

```
select CONVERT( CHAR(10),MyColumn,104)
```